# How to implement a "pop down" like in gmail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to implement a pop down panel like on the top bar of Gmail.  If you click on the Setting icon, your name, or the Share link, a panel drops down...is there a jquery plugin or something that will allow me to quickly implement something to give a similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/craigm/p4ek9/) that show how you can implement something like this.

Basically, you're capturing clicks on the body element, if they clicked on settings, you show the "panel" div. If they clicked something else, you hide it.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'settings') {
            $('#panel').show();
        } else {
            $('#panel').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="settings">Settings</span>
<div id="panel">
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#panel { display: none;  border: 1px solid #000;}
```

Comment: So one more question--in gmail, when you click on the link, the panel below displays, but the panel is connected to the link, giving it a "tab" effect.  Any idea how I can modify your code to add that effect?  Is it all done in CSS?

Comment: Yes, it's all done with CSS. I didn't go into that much in the example since it would have to be integrated with the rest of your site and any solution I gave you wouldn't necessarily work once you did that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non jQuery cross browser solution I made this for someone on here yesterday:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/H4CLU/

It drops down when you click `button` and hides when you click it again, or anywhere in the document that isn't part of the drop down.

Only thing you'd need to change is probably some CSS stuff to style it nicely.

Comment: Thanks PaulPRO--just what I needed.  I'd prefer to do this in jquery though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I suggest to use jQuery (everytime you use JS). It is really easy to create a layer like this:

```
<div id="layer">content</div>
<a id="button" href="#">show</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document)ready(function(){
    $('#layer').hide();
    $('#button').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#layer').show();
    });
});
</script>
```